# Почему не скачивается проект с bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Всем привет.

Есть аккаунт на bitbucket, в нем репозиторий (site), в котором папка с сайтом и папка .git, залитые с рабочего сервера. Хочу скопировать данный репозиторий вместе с файлами проекта на локальный компьютер (Windows).

Запускаю Cygwin-терминал, вхожу в папку с локальными доменами, ввожу команду

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:mynamespace/emk.git
```

После этого вижу, что скачалась папка emk, внутри которой папка .git. На этом все.

Вопрос - можно ли из консоли на локальном компе ввести команду, которая скачает и папку гита, и все файлы проекта?

В меню Source вижу это

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Может репозиторий приватный?

Comment: Проверь ключи доступа SSH. Твой ключ добавлен в репозитории ?

Comment: Репозиторий приватный, ключа нет, использую базовую авторизацию, да. Но при чем тут это, если папка .git скачивается?

Comment: «команду, которая скачает и папку гита, и все файлы проекта» — эта команда и есть `git clone`. А что показывает команда `git log` в папке `emk` после клонирования?

Answer (score 0):

Если репозиторий приватный, ключа нет, то скачиваться будут пустые папки. Все остальное по ключу

Comment: Никогда такого не видел. Это какая-то фича битбакета?

Comment: Добавил ключ в основных настройках аккаунта. Добавил ключ для конкретного репозитория. Добавил хосты bitbacket в ../.ssh/settings

Стало выводиться сообщение: 

Cloning into 'emk'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.